# A one liner for stashing and simultaneously naming untracked changes and files using git stash

Tags: git, git-stash

Here is the situation:

I have an untracked file in my repository. I'd like to stash this file using `git stash`  and I'd like to name the stash myself. So I found out about `git stash save "message"`, but it seems that this command doesn't work for untracked files. So I need to first run `git stash -u` then rename the stash.

Is there any workaround for this issue? if this can be considered an issue. Can I stash the untracked files and simultaneously naming them myself in one command?

I am aware of other possibilities such as first staging using `git add` then using `git stash save "message"` and as I mentioned earlier it's also possible to first run `git stash -u` then rename the stash, but I'm looking for one liner command to stash and name my untracked changes and let's say I don't wanna stage or commit my changes.

Comment: Huh? `git stash save -u 'whatever your message'` – it's right there at the top of the [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

Comment: @knittl thanks for the heads up, it seems that I'm not that versatile after all... LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by simply running the following command

```
git stash save -u "your message or the name of the stash"
```

This command is presented on the [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).